# React state variable is undefined inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state variable `dataSource` that has some data in it.

In a parent component I have the following:

```
updateFeed = newItem => {
    this.setState({ dataSource: this.state.dataSource.data.unshift(newItem) })
    console.log(this.state.dataSource.data)
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.dataSource.data)
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={props => (
            <Feed {...props} feedData={this.state.dataSource.data} updateFeed={this.updateFeed} />
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/profile/:id" exact component={props => <Profile {...props} />} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

`updateFeed` is called from the child component.

```
onSubmit = () => {
    const newPost = newData // some new data
    this.props.updateFeed(newPost)
  }
```

The `updateFeed` function is getting executed on submit, and the `console.log` is giving the updated data. But inside the render function `this.state.dataSource.data` is `undefined`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why you are calling `unshift`? that mutate your state, which should be avoid.

Comment: I have to insert the element in the front of the array.

Comment: then just use spread operator `[newItem, ...this.state.dataSource.data]` instead. If you mutate your state, your setState would not correctly working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do `dataSource: dataSource.data` in your setState call, therefore `dataSource.data` in your render method will actually access `dataSource.data.data` which is probably undefined. May change `updatedFeed` to:

```
 updateFeed = newItem => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
       dataSource: {
           ...prev.dataSource,
           data: prev.dataSource.data.concat(newItem)
       }
    }));      
  }
```

Which ensures a pure state.

Answer (score 1):

It is because previously, `this.state.dataSource` is an object having key `data`. So even you are setting new value in  `updateFeed` but in the very next line, state has not been updated yet. React does this asynchronously. so your log statement is showing old data.

You need to update state like this

```
const dataSource = this.state.dataSource;
dataSource.data.unshift(newItem);
this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource })
```